# Drupal 7-Views Taxonomy Parent Child URL

Tags: drupal-7, view, taxonomy, drupal-contextual-filters

Facing an issue with getting views to generate a proper URL similar to the way taxonomy allows me to click on a child term with the path: domain/term/artwork/mirrors (path alias is configured)

Vocabulary:

**Product sections**
- Artwork
-- Hand Painted
-- Mirrors
- Novelty
-- Ceramic Mugs
-- Stickers
-- Books
- Wearables
-- Shirts
-- Shoes
-- Personalized Shoes

I currently have a taxonomy view with 2 contextual filters: Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) AND Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) is configured with...
• Depth: 1
• Set the breadcrumb for the term parents
• Display contents of "No results found"
• Specify validation criteria - Taxonomy Term from 'Product Category' vocabulary.
• Filter Value Type: Term name converte to Term ID
• Check Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values

Page Path: /category/%

With my current setup, I can go to: domain/category/artwork and this displays all content which is categorized under artwork (hand painted and mirrors)

What i need is domain/category/artwork/hand-painted but it displays all artwork regardless if its hand painted or mirrors. 
BUT this path, domain/category/hand-painted works correctly.  How do i make the url respect the parent term. It seems like views cant interpret a parent - child relationship.

I plan on creating parent term pages outside of this view so the parent term path /category/artwork won't be handled here.

Last thing to note is the node path pattern: 
category/[node:field-category:parents:join:/]/[node:field-category:name]/[node:title]

• domain/category/artwork/hand-painted/fancy-painting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the Taxonomy Views Integration module and specifying my existing view page.
-https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi

Next I had to modify the contextual filter to only have 'Basic Validation' and also remove "%" from the page view path.

Now the URL's are exactly what core taxonomy builds but it outputs the view i created

Hope this helps someone else! :-)